# how to use get_instance() in custom library file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my custom class in library folder in codeigniter

```
class Commonlib {

        public function __construct()
        {      
                 $ci=& get_instance();
                 $ci->load->database();
        }
           function getcountries(){

                return  $ci->db->get("countries")->result();
            }
                function cities(){ 
                return  $ci->db->get("cities")->result();
            }
    }
```

here is my view

```
$results=$this->commonlib->getcountries();
   foreach ($results as $row)
   { 
       echo '<a   href="#">'.$row->country .'</a><br>';
   }
```

error is Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined variable: ci
how to load database in library construct function

Comment: Try with `$this->CI` instead of `$ci`

Comment: why did you load the data base in library auto load the Datebase in autoload.php file,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code. there are some changes suggested

```
class Commonlib {
    private $ci;
    public function __construct()
    {      
             $this -> ci=& get_instance();
             $this -> ci->load->database();
    }
       function getcountries(){

            return  $this -> ci->db->get("countries")->result();
        }
            function cities(){ 
            return  $this -> ci->db->get("cities")->result();
        }
}
```

**Note:** In your old code `$db` in `__construct()` method will have scope with in that method only. For get the `ci` object globally with in that entire class I used `$this`.

Comment: @GhulamAbbas, Glad to help. Please up vote and accept the answer.. :) So others can easily find the answer

Comment: any downside for using this?

Answer (score 0):

please try to create helper

create helper in dir app/helpers/

layout_helper.php

```
function getcountries()
{

    $CI = & get_instance();     
    return  $CI->db->get("countries")->result();   
}
```

and now that function use is view file 
like that :

```
$result = getcountries();

foreach ($results as $row)
{ 
   echo '<a   href="#">'.$row->country .'</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: i have the cities  then there  write again  $CI = & get_instance();  as you i have 100 function then write 100 line again again but i want to write in one  line in the whole file